# Make only one row action to insert and other update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an validation process which will return data in this format,

```
DECLARE @MyDbTable TABLE (Id int, ACTION varchar(10))
```

It include 2 fields. Other fields are omitted for brevity. This `MyDbTable` include action 'Insert', 'Update', 'Ignore'. Let say I have the following data,

```
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (1, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (1, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (2, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (2, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (2, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (2, 'Insert')
INSERT INTO @MyDbTable (Id, ACTION)
VALUES (2, 'Ignore')
```

I need to only consider 'Insert' action. There should be only 1 action per Id with 'Insert' action and other should be 'Update'. Here is the final result whihc I am looking,

```
Id  ACTION
1   Insert
1   Update
2   Insert
2   Update
2   Update
2   Update
2   Ignore
```

How can I update @MyDbTable to achieve the above result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this approach using a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH toUpdate AS
(
    SELECT Id, Action,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by t.id order by ID, Action)
    FROM MyDbTable t
    WHERE ACTION = 'Insert'
)
UPDATE d
SET ACTION = 'Update'
FROM toUpdate d
WHERE RN > 1;
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16dc2/1/1)</kbd>